# Are Mac App Store apps allowed to read .plist files of other apps?

Tags: macos, sandbox, appstore-sandbox

Is it allowed for Mac apps available on the Mac App Store to read .plist files of a (built in) app or do I need to sandbox it completely (Scripting bridge does not provide the functionality)?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to read the plist of an app, provided you have the correct path (e.g. /Applications/Preview.app/Contents/Info.plist).

Starting in March, though, the sandboxing rules will prevent that. You cannot read/write outside of your container without explicit user permission (Powerbox)

Maybe what you are trying to do is better done through NSWorkspace, though.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html